# Inline try except

Tags: python, try-except

I have a JSON, in which there are multiple `{}`, that all have the `'admissionCountTotal'` element, except for one. The one without this element can be anyone, but for the sake of this example, let's say we know which one it is.

```
{
    "movie":{
        "boxOffice":[
            {"admissionCountTotal":123},
            {"admissionCountTotal":456},
            {"admissionCountTotal":1234},
            {"admissionCountTotal":1253},
            {"admissionCount":"this is not admissionCountTotal"},
            {"admissionCountTotal":61723},
            {"admissionCountTotal":1423},
            {"admissionCountTotal":12323},
            {"admissionCountTotal":5123}
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the max value that can be found in these `admissionCountTotal`. This works, so I have basically found how to do it :

```
max(data['movie']['boxOffice'][sem]['admissionCountTotal'] for sem in xrange(0,3))
```

However, this doesn't :

```
max(data['movie']['boxOffice'][sem]['admissionCountTotal'] for sem in xrange(0,56))
```

For two reasons :

- trying to get `data['movie']['boxOffice'][4]['admissionCountTotal']` gives an error.
- trying to get `data['movie']['boxOffice'][9]['admissionCountTotal']` and upper than 9 gives an error as there aren't any element above that. However, I can't know how many elements there are (except for the fact that there can't be more than 56 elements)

Therefore, I'd like to have some kind of inline `try` structure, which I suspect would solve both my problems. Is it possible ? If not, how else can I get around my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need try/except at all; you just need a loop through the elements of boxoffice rather than an integer range.

```
max(item['admissionCountTotal'] for item in data['movie']['boxOffice'])
```

Since at least one of those items does not actually have a total, you can use `get` with a default:

```
max(item.get('admissionCountTotal', 0) for item in data['movie']['boxOffice'])
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I had thought about that (which is kind of like MySQL's `IFNULL()` if I understand well), but since it was returning an error, I thought a `try` was necessary. Thanks. Just for the sake of knowledge though, is there some kind of inline `try` ?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that; try and except are statements. Generally though there's usually a functional way of doing it, as here. If you really couldn't avoid exceptions, you could define a separate function that returns the value or catches the error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And if I wanted the value of the last one of `admissionCountTotal` (5123 in my example in the question), how could I get that ?

Comment: Nevermind, found it ! : `[item.get('admissionCountTotal', 0) for item in data['movie']['boxOffice']][-1]`

Comment: @fmalaussena You don't need a loop to get the last item, just do `data['movie']['boxOffice'][-1]['admissionCountTotal'] `, or `data['movie']['boxOffice'][-1].get('admissionCountTotal')`, which will evaluate to `None` if the last 'boxOffice' item doesn't have a 'admissionCountTotal'.